# Android design button for mdpi

Tags: android

I know it is a common problem but I didn't find the solution. When designing buttons for android you have to design for specific DPI but with MDPI there is a problem;

The smallest mdpi is 320x480, so i created the button to fit the smallest screen, but if u see at the 5,4 device which is mdpi to it is 480x854. The buttons looks to small for that screensize but i can't make them bigger because they don't fit on the 320x480 screen anymore?

Is there a an other way to make the buttons fit the screen? For tablet it also uses the mdpi images so it looks very tiny..

Comment: good question its of my use .....+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a bit longer I've found the answer:

U have to add

```
drawable-large-mdpi
```

as folder to the res, and place the buttons there